# Returning to the menu & exiting the program

Tags: c++, menu, switch-statement, exit

(C++) 
So i'm writing a program for my assignment and it requires for the program to prompt the user to return to the menu or quit the program after each case, the problem is i'm not sure how to implement this efficiently. Any ideas? Also for quitting, I would like to call the last function called 'exit'

```
 #include <iostream>                                                                //libraries


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int menu(double pi);
int circleArea(double pi);
int circleCircum(double pi);                                                    //function declarations for the demanded shapes, passing pi in order to reuse it in both circle calculations
int rectanArea();
int triangArea();
int cubVol();
void exit();

int main()
{
    double pi = 3.14159265359;                                                  //declaration of pi which I will be using in the circles (passed)
    menu(pi);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int menu(double pi)                                                             //menu for choosing a shape
{
    int choice = 0;
    cout << "Shape Calculator Created By:\n\nPlease select what you wish to calculate:\n\n1 - Area of a Circle\n\n2 - Circumference of a Circle\n\n3 - Area of a Rectangle\n\n4 - Area of a Triangle\n\n5 - Volume of a Cuboid\n\n ";
    cin >> choice;
    system("CLS");

     switch (choice)                                                                //switch case for each shape
        {
        case 1:
            circleArea(pi);
            break;
        case 2:
            circleCircum(pi);
            break;
        case 3:
            rectanArea();
            break;
        case 4:
            triangArea();
            break;
        case 5:
            cubVol();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input! Please try again.\n\n";
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}

int circleArea(double pi)                                                       //the area of circle function
{
    double radius = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the radius of your circle:\n\n";                      //asks for the radius first
    cin >> radius;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The area of your Circle is:\n\n" << radius*radius*pi << "cm/2\n\n";                                //display the calculation which is calculated using the user input, essentially the formula is PI*radius(squared) just reversed
    return 0;
}


int circleCircum(double pi)                                                     //the circumference of circle function
{
    double radius = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter the radius of your circle:\n\n";                      //asks for radius first
    cin >> radius;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The circumference of your Circle is:\n\n" << pi*radius * 2 << "cm\n\n";                            //calculates the circumference using the user input, formula is 2*PI*radius but reversed
    return 0;
}

int rectanArea()                                                                //function for area of rectangle
{
    double rectanHeight = 0.0;
    double rectanWidth = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter the height of your Rectangle:\n\n";                   //asks for input for the height first
    cin >> rectanHeight;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Height = " << rectanHeight << endl << endl << "Please enter the width of your Rectangle\n\n";      //shows the inputted height above, then asks for input of width
    cin >> rectanWidth;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The area of your Rectangle is:\n\n" << rectanHeight*rectanWidth << "cm/2\n\n";                     //calculates the area of rectangle using the input, formula is height*width then displays it
    return 0;
}

int triangArea()                                                                //function for area of triangle
{
    double triangBase = 0.0;
    double triangHeight = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter the base measurement of your Triangle\n\n";           //asks for input of the base first
    cin >> triangBase;  
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Base = " << triangBase << endl << endl << "Please enter the height of your Triangle\n\n";          //displays inputted base and then asks for the height
    cin >> triangHeight;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The area of your Triangle is:\n\n" << triangBase*triangHeight / 2 << "cm/2\n\n";                   //calculates area using user input and displays it, formula is base*height/2
    return 0;
}

int cubVol()                                                                    //function for volume of a cuboid
{
    double cubLength = 0.0;
    double cubWidth = 0.0;
    double cubHeight = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter the length of your Cuboid\n\n";                       //asks for input of length first
    cin >> cubLength;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Length = " << cubLength << endl << endl << "Please enter the width of your Cuboid\n\n";            //displays inputted length and asks for the width
    cin >> cubWidth;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Length = " << cubLength << endl << "Width = " << cubWidth << endl << endl << "Please enter the height of your Cuboid:\n\n";        //displays inputted length and width, asks for the height finally
    cin >> cubHeight;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The volume of your Cuboid is:\n\n" << cubLength*cubWidth*cubHeight << "cm/3\n\n";                  //displays the calculation using inputted information, formula is length*width*height
    return 0;

}

void exit()
{
        cout << "**************************************" << endl;
        cout << "**************************************" << endl;
        cout << "*******    T H A N K  Y O U    *******" << endl;
        cout << "*******    F O R  U S I N G    *******" << endl;
        cout << "******* T H I S  P R O G R A M *******" << endl;
        cout << "**************************************" << endl;
        cout << "**************************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Read about loops in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Yes I thought about using do_while loops although i'm not sure how to use them to quit and to return to the menu in one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main, substitute menu(pi) with:

```
char choice;
bool exitNow = false;

do{
    menu(pi);
    cout<<"Return (r) or quit (q)?"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice == 'q')
        exitNow = true;
} while (!exitNow);
exit();
```

It should work even if I haven't tested it.

EDIT:
The code above doesn't check if a correct input is entered. This should solve:

```
char choice = 0;
bool exitNow = false;

do{
    menu(pi);

    do{
        cout<<"Return (r) or quit (q)?"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
    }
    while( !(choice == 'r' || choice == 'q') && cout<<"Invalid input!"<<endl);

    if(choice == 'q')
        exitNow = true;
} while (!exitNow);
exit();
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this although after enter r or q it only displays "invalid input". Would you mind explaining a bit of this code? I only actually started programming in September :P

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Edited and corrected. I use do-while loops to run the instructions at least 1 time. After menu(pi) is executed, the user is prompt with a message which asks for a 'r' or a 'q' (you can use integer too, just change the type). The inner while condition checks if choice is incorrect and, if it is so, prints "Invalid input!" (cout is executed only if the first condition is true). After that, if choice is 'q', exitNow is set to true and that ends the loop. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah that makes it a lot clearer, thanks a lot.
One more thing, what do the inner bracker actually do?:

`(!(choice == 'r' || choice == 'q') && cout << "Invalid input!" << endl)`

Comment: I have to negate `choice == 'r' || choice == 'q'`, so it is `!(choice == 'r' || choice == 'q')`. Writing `!choice == 'r' || choice == 'q'` means negate only choice (which is true, because it is different from 0) so I have basically a `false == 'r' || choice == 'q'`

Comment: Just noticed I could have used an `&&` instead of `||` without the negation.`choice == 'r' && choice == 'q' && cout<<"Invalid input!"<<endl`

Comment: Sorry, `choice != 'r' && choice != 'q' && cout<<"Invalid input!"<<endl`